# Time complexicity of recursive function

Tags: combinatorics, computer-science, gamma-function, recursive-algorithms

I have a recursive function f(n) with time complexity

$$O(f(n)) = O\left(\binom{n}{n/2} \cdot f\left(\frac{n}{2}\right)^2\right)$$

I tried to simplify it, but don't have enough mathematical skills. The only thing that I found out is that

$$ \binom{n}{n/2} = 2^n \cdot \frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{n}{2} + \frac{1}{2}\right)}{\sqrt{\pi} \cdot \Gamma(\frac{n}{2} + 1)}$$

Comment: I suppose just iterative substitution, like $O(f(n)) = O(\frac{n!}{(n/2)!(n/2)!}f(n/2)^2) = O(\frac{n!}{(n/2)!(n/2)!}\frac{(n/2)!(n/2)!}{((n/2)!)^4}f(n/4)^4)$ will give something like $O(n! \cdot O(1)^n)$ which to me seems like $O(n!)$

Comment: But as I have writen above, $$ \binom{n}{n/2} = \frac{n!}{(n/2)!(n/2!)}=2^n \cdot \frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{n}{2} + \frac{1}{2}\right)}{\sqrt{\pi} \cdot \Gamma(\frac{n}{2} + 1)}$$ and the right part of this expresstion ($$\frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{n}{2} + \frac{1}{2}\right)}{\sqrt{\pi} \cdot \Gamma(\frac{n}{2} + 1)}$$ seems me like some function that converts to some constant and is deffinitely lower than 1 so I thing that it should be O(e^n) or better, but I am not sure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have allready solved it.

$\binom{n}{\frac{n}{2}} = 2^n \cdot \frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{n}{2} + \frac{1}{2}\right)}{\sqrt{\pi} \cdot \Gamma\left(\frac{n}{2} + 1\right)}$

As you can see here: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=binom(n,+n%2F2)

Now we define function

$a(n) := \frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{n}{2} + \frac{1}{2}\right)}{\sqrt{\pi} \cdot \Gamma\left(\frac{n}{2} + 1\right)}$

Because gamma function is growing function for every real number bigger than one, than $0 < a(n) < 1$. If we derive this function, as you can see here

https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=derive(gamma(n%2F2+%2B+1%2F2)%2F(gamma(n%2F2+%2B+1)*sqrt(pi)))

we can see that derivation is negative, but very fast is very close to zero, so the function $a(n)$ is decreasing, but very slovly and in compare to function $2^n$, we can say, that it is a constant. So we have simplified the problem to

$O(f(n)) = O\left(2^n \cdot \left(f(\frac{n}{2})\right)^2\right) = O\left(2^n \cdot \left(\prod\limits_{i=1}^{Log_2(n)} 2^{n\cdot2^{-i}}\right)^2\right)$

And beacause

$ \prod\limits_{i=1}^{Log_2(n)} 2^{n\cdot2^{-i}} = 2^{n-1}$

As you can see here: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=product(2%5E(n*2%5E(-i))),+i+%3D+1+to+log_2(n)

Than we can make result

$O(f(n)) = O\left(2^n \cdot \left(2^{n-1}\right)^2\right)  = O\left(2^n \cdot 2^{2n-2}\right) = O\left(2^{4n-2}\right) = O\left(2^n\right)$

So we can see that final complexity is exponential